# Запуск программы с подключением дополнительной библиотеки

Tags: c++, windows, windbg

Подскажите, как запустить программу с дополнительной библиотекой. Требуется подгрузить библиотеку во время старта программы.

Я могу подгрузить библиотеку через вставку кода в программу, но со времени запуска пройдет секунд 10. А нужно чтобы библиотека запустилась раньше операций любых с памятью.

Я вижу два возможных варианта:

1. Запустить программу указав дополнительную библиотеку. Как это сделать?
2. Запустить программу из дебаггера и подгрузить библиотеку в точке старта. Из WinDbg подгрузить не удается. .load dll_path выдает The call to LoadLibrary(C:\My\...\meminjectd.dll) failed, Win32 error 0n193   "%1 не является приложением Win32."
3. Написать программу на C++, которая запустит указанную программу, остановит после старта и подгрузит библиотеку. Подскажите, как это сделать.

Comment: Какую задачу решаете? Вы хотите свои реализации функций работы с памятью подставить или промониторить их?

Answer (score 1):

Если я ничего не путаю, добавление DLL в секцию импортов приведет к тому, что загрузчик загрузит ее в процессе загрузки приложения и передаст управление на DllMain().